# Access modules child modules service from main controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this module as my main app which uses `api`:

```
var app = angular.module('app.main', ['api']);

app.controller('Home', function($scope, api, search){
    $scope.search = function(){
        api.search.lookup($scope.domain);
        search.lookup($scope.domain);
    };
});
```

I then have `api` which uses a few other modules like this:

```
var app = angular.module('api', [
    'api.search'
    // other modules here
]);

app.service('api', function($cookies, $http, $rootScope, search){
    // Some more code
});
```

The search search `module` looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('api.search', []);

app.service('search', function($scope, $http){
    this.lookup = function(domain){
        // query
    };
});
```

When I run my controller and inject `api`, I can not access `search` because I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'lookup' of undefined`, and if I inject `search` instead, I get this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">copeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%search
```

So, how can I access search from my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as it seems, is that you are trying to inject `$scope` into a service generating function.

`$scope` is a local injectable available only for controllers, which makes sense, since scope is contextual to where the controller is defined and it has no meaning for singleton services.

Instead, you could inject `$rootScope` into a service, if needed.

```
app.service('search', function($rootScope, $http){
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Oops sorry, I do have `api` defined, I just forgot it in the code

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, ok, I removed the reference to `api` as a second problem

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, then something else is going on, since it works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/WZUiHpLgI2MQeVfCU9JY?p=preview

Comment: Nvm it works, but I also have to add `this.search = search;` to my `api` service.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, ok... but again, your specific error was the attempt to inject `$scope` into a service